# issues with deploying MERN stack on linode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mern, vercel, linode

I've been trying to deploy my **MERN** stack on **Linode**. the frontend is built with **NEXT.JS** and below is the configuration file for my **nginx** for the reverse proxy. but the issue i'm having is when i visit my domain, i can view the site but the CSS isn't being displayed. the css is beeing handled by **tailwind** i.e, the site has no css. the process manager i'm using is pm2 to run both production environments for the client and server. ive ran **yarn build** and all the necessary commands necessary for production on the client side all to no avail. would really appreciate some assistance as i'm new to this. Thanks

```
  server {
    root /root/app/.next;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com ;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_min_length 256;

    location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Replace with the actual address of your Node.js app
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

   location /api/v1 {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

     location /_next {
    alias /root/app/.next;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}

location /static {
    alias /root/app/.next/static/;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
    expires 365d;
    access_log off;
}

}
```